# Invoking another URL

Tags: c#, .net, http, url, httpwebrequest

```
    string url = "http://foo.com/bar?id=" + id + "&more=" + more;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I m trying make a call to another server, and getting back the following:

```
 |FATAL|The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable. (REF #1)
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.
```

Why am i getting this error? and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> **10.4.7 406 Not Acceptable**
>
> The resource identified by the request
>   is only capable of generating response
>   entities which have content
>   characteristics not acceptable
>   according to the accept headers sent
>   in the request.

Review the accept headers that your request is sending , and the content server in that URL ; )

---

**BONUS**

- To see the accept headers: browse to
  the URL and use FireBug (HTML tab).
- To set the accept headers into your
  request use the [HttpWebRequest
  Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest_members%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: so you are saying that i should just invoke it, not expect any response?

Comment: Hi User177883 (you have to set your nick ; ) hehehe, what kind of resource is being served in that URL (an image, a HTML page, it's a web service maybe)?

Comment: i m just invoking the url with the parameters, that sit.

Comment: Hi again!, can you browse to the URL? (including the parameters you're passing)

Comment: Use firebug to get the HTTP headers you're sending to the server. Then set them manually to the HttpWebRequest object - see the MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest_members%28VS.80%29.aspx Tell me if it works : )